# JSF rendered multiple combined conditions

Tags: jsf, rendered-attribute

I need to give condition like

```
 if((a == 12 and b == 13) or(a == 12 and b == 15))
```

in JSF rendered attribute.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Assuming that "a" and "b" are bean properties

```
rendered="#{bean.a==12 and (bean.b==13 or bean.b==15)}"
```

You may look at [JSF EL operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html)